# how can I load data insinde tag div using ZK

Tags: java, css, jakarta-ee, zk

I want to see progress increase in progressbar, i already use progressmeter of ZK. but now i'm using an other progressbar in div like that

```
<div if="${item.progres ge '35'}" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"> 
    <span class="sr-only"></span>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.
Do you want to load data on the fly so its increases progressbar?
OR Do you want to load data once so the progress bar shows some kind of progress?

AND

What's ZK Progressmeter and "like" that what else are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it possiblle.

You have to need an image what you can set behind the span of the progress bar.
[I created a fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1nks62h/1-progress-meter-bar-in-other-color) (the one from ZK Demo) where I do this with a gradient image found on the internet.

So the only thing what you have to add is this :

```
<style>
    .z-progressmeter-image {
        background: url("http://i810.photobucket.com/albums/zz22/PinkSith/Nubar/top-new_zps72ae9651.jpg");
    }
</style>
```

You just need to create the correct image, and it would be good.

Comment: Thank you soo much my friend but really i had already do that after using an other progress bar, my problem is that i'm using Dashbroard to see this progress so i'm using timer of zk  to refresh my page , and when i'm using progress bar of zk everytime i see progress repeat in zero and continu to  progress .

Comment: you should not refresh the page. Refreshing page leads to new instance of viewmodel/composer.  Work with the events correct.

Comment: I'm working with the event like taht `<timer id="timer" delay="3000" repeats="true" onTimer="@command('reloadListbox')" />` , i still see progress repeat in zero and continue

Comment: Thank you , i just sent you an invitation on linkedin